# Is there a module for viewing sugarCRM contacts and prospects on Map?

Tags: dictionary, integration, sugarcrm

i need to create a module for SugarCRM where the user can see a map of all his contacts/prospects and can make searches relative to areas.

For example, show me all my conctats in Milan or show me the leads in Tuscany.

Is there a module that does something similar?I'v found [this](http://www.sugarforge.org/projects/mappingforsugar) module, but it seesm i have to pay, and it's for sugar 5.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any free google map implementations for sugar, but this description might help:

- [How to Add a Google Map to a Module in Sugar](http://www.sugarcrm.com/kb/custom/studio/how-to-add-a-google-map-to-a-module-in-sugar/)

Or else these modules exists for SugarCRM 6:

- [iNetMaps](http://www.sugarexchange.com/product_details.php?product=668)
- [SynoGeoloc](http://www.sugarexchange.com/product_details.php?product=466)

Answer (score 0):

JJWDesign Google Maps Package for SugarCRM is a free package that allows for mapping contacts and prospects. Search for it or go to http://WWW.jjwdesign.com for more information.